# how we use slick transaction on service layer for making a transaction System

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

in my service layer i want to insert transaction-ally if insert than all the three row are inserted in database !!

Service Layer is

```
def service(userRow, addressDao, contactDao) = DB.withTransaction { implicit session => 
    userDao.insert(userRow)
    addressDao.insert(addressRow)
    contactDao.insert(contactRow)
}
```

my dao layer is

```
def insert(userRow: UsersRow) = DB.withTransaction { implicit session =>
    user += userRow
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your insert method to

```
def insert(userRow:UsersRow)(implicit session: Session)={
    user+=userRow
}
```

The session will be propagated and all inserts use the same session. If the session is using a transaction as your example did, then it will be done in the same transaction.