# Slick Repo methods all participating in one Service's Transaction

Tags: scala, slick-2.0

I currently have a set of Data Access Objects named with the convention `*SlickRepo`. So for instance, `UserSlickRepo`, `DistributionSlickRepo`, `ContentSlickRepo`, etc...

Each of these Repos have methods on them that basically follow this convention:

```
trait SomethingRepoImpl extends SomethingRepo {
  val somethingRepo: SomethingRepo = new SomethingRepoImpl

  class SomethingRepoImpl extends SomethingRepo with MySlickDatastore {

    def getSomething(id: UUID): Either[SomethingNotFoundError, Something] = {
      getDatabase withDynSession {
        // Slick stuff
      }
    }
    def createSomething .....
  }
}
```

Now up at a Service level, we bake in this repo class and we have methods that look like this:

```
trait SomethingServiceImpl extends SomethingService {

  dep: SomethingRepo with SomethingElseRepo =>


  val somethingService = new SomethingServiceImpl

  class SomethingServiceImpl extends SomethingService {

    def createSomethingGood(): Either[SomeError, (Something, SomethingElse)] = {
      (dep.somethingRepo.createSomething, dep.somethingElseRepo.createSomethingElse)
    }

  }
}
```

We now desire to have `createSomethingGood` actually run the two repo methods within a transaction.  Since all the Slick stuff is locked up in the Slick specific Repo methods, what's the best way to do this?  I'm not opposed to having Slick-specific code in my `*ServiceImpl` classes (I mean weird, but ok), however does that mean I have to change my Repo classes to remove the `getDatabase withDynSession` type code all together and instead pass in a session from the service layer?  To me, that just seems... wrong.

Comment: You can have a transactional service with implicit session as [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398482/how-we-use-slick-transaction-on-service-layer-for-making-a-transaction-system). Side note: are you sure you Repos are actually Repositories, not DAO objects?

Answer (score 4):

From my point of view the right approach is to add `createSomething` and `createSomethingElse` to one `*Repo` (`SomethingRepo` or `SomethingElseRepo`) transactional method (`withTransaction {...}`). It's not a beautiful solution but as simple as possible for me and because these entities are logically connected (which we can see from this code `(dep.somethingRepo.createSomething, dep.somethingElseRepo.createSomethingElse)`) I think it's not a big violation to mix operation on 2 entities in one DAO class. Please, fix me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure that creating a custom *Repo class anytime a service method needs to call two repo calls within a transaction is feasible in my case.

Comment: @ThaDon, not creating custom but reuse one of already existing. In your example they are `SomethingRepo` or `SomethingElseRepo`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is another way. I haven't tried it myself, but the idea is that you could have a Session wrapper that actually gets passed to the Repo.

That wrapper would have to be created at the service layer, but you can abstract the specific implementation on a companion object so the service layer doesn't actually deal with Slick, but rather something like

```
SessionWrapper.transactional: Session
```

I hope this helps, I'll add more to the response if I get the change to give it a try myself.